# linq to sql query problem

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have table Profile and Table Configuration 
One Profile have many configuration 
how to select only Configuration with have at least one profile  In Linq To sql

i try something like that but its not work :

```
public static IQueryable<Configuration> WithProfile(
    this IQueryable<Configuration> configurations)
{
    return configurations.Where(
                      configuration => configuration.Profiles.Count() > 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

more efficient to just check if `Any` rather using the count, but it sounds like something else is the cause of your problems

```
public static IQueryable<Configuration> WithProfile(
    this IQueryable<Configuration> configurations)
{
    return configurations.Where(c => c.Profiles.Any());
}
```